# Does paragon/renegade/neutral morality affect the storyline or available missions?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Will focusing primarily on paragon or renegade (or neutral) affect the storyline in any major way *(IIRC, in previous games it was mostly just dialogue options)*?  Will I miss out on anything, such as items or missions, if I do this?

Comment: You should probably expand the title to cover both alignments.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: Good idea; done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53166/how-does-reputation-work-in-mass-effect-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apparently](http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Endings), the final dialogue option of the game depends on your Paragon/Renegade score, and not just your overall reputation. And it does so in a rather strict way - you must have either gone 100% Paragon or 100% Renegade to unlock that option.

It doesn't make a huge difference to the story though, and every other option only depends on overall reputation, so it's not *that* big of a deal.

Comment: Actually, turns out that this is wrong - to get the paragon or renegade option for the final confrontation you need to have given the appropriate response in all six prior cases - this may require some Investigate options along the way.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer is no. **There’s no penalty for mixing Paragon and Renegade**

Your paragon/renegade/neutral morality does not affect story line or available missions. All your paragon, renegade and neutral points are added together to make up your total reputation. Special dialogue/decision options may become available  when your reputation increases, regardless of whether you did or chose more renegade or more paragon actions/dialogue options.

Read [this blog entry](http://blog.bioware.com/2012/03/01/reputation-in-mass-effect-3/) - it explains everything!

*Excerpt:*

"On your squad/powers screen, you’ll see a bar made up of a mix of red and blue. The red represents your Renegade points, while the blue represents your Paragon points. Reputation points that aren’t Paragon or Renegade don’t get their own color – they make the bar get bigger while keeping the same red/blue ratio.

Note that the bar has lines marking various points of progression. Key dialog options at important moments in the game are locked off – you can only take them if your reputation is high enough – and each of those lines marks a checkpoint. If you see that you’re a bit short of hitting a new line, and someone has just said something like, “Let’s head down to [that person's homeworld] and finish this once and for all,” it may be worth your time to go do a couple of side-quests first, just to see if you can reach that line."

Comment: Hello Kat, welcome on Gaming.SE. Maybe you could  expand your answer by quoting relevant parts of you link? On case the link rot, the information should still be available.

Comment: Thanks Jupotter! I added a brief explanation & an excerpt from the blog entry