# Do any missions force me to get paragon or renegade points?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I know [morality does not block off gameplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53684/4012) but I was wondering if doing certain missions automatically earns me either paragon or renegade points. Are there any missions that are impossible to complete nicely and will mean I always earn renegade points for finishing (and vice versa) or will there always be a choice on how to complete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will never be a point where you are forced to get renegade points (see the comments for a possible exception), or forced to get paragon points.

There are points where you have to pick one or the other, but never a point where you're offered only one option.

They changed this from Mass Effect 2 where at the end of a mission you'd get 5 points each. People complained that they wanted to play an entirely renegade or entirely paragon playthrough, but were forced to get some points in the other alignment.

They changed this system to getting neutral reputation now. The only time you get paragon or renegade reputation, is when you make a specific choice.

Comment: Yes there are, the rachnai mission forces you to get five renegade either decision, whether you save her or not, at least if the queen is a reaper.

Comment: @BenBrocka Really? That seems against everything I've ever read about the Mass Effect 3 Reputation system. I never encountered this coz I saved the queen.

Comment: It seems to be the exception to the rule, but both options give renegade points. I chose the top option which still gave me 5? renegade points. Until certain irresistible Renegade Interrupts that was my only Renegade rep.

Answer (score 1):

That will never happened with the new neutral reputations points.

However, you can considered that in the final mission if you are not enough Paragon,

> you are forced to use a renegade interruption to stop general bastard Illusive man to kill Anderson.

Comment: We have a spoiler tag you can use for when you post spoilers. Just put ">!" in front of the text and it will hide it like it does now due to yijangs edit.