# What advantages are there to high reputation?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Reputation work in Mass Effect 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53166/how-does-reputation-work-in-mass-effect-3)

So in Mass Effect  3 Paragon and Renegade points go into a single Reputation meter. I also noticed most classes have a skill which improves your ability to gain reputation period (not specific paragon/renegade rep).

What effects does a high "agnostic" Reputation value have, regardless of what % of your reputation is Paragon or Renegade?

Comment: This is covered in [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/53167/160).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bearing in mind that thanks to EA, Sony, Microsoft and/or brick-and-mortar stores demanding different street dates for the EU, I can't confirm this hypothesis for another two days when I'll finally be able to actually play, but...

The way I understood the little talk about neutral reputation is that it magnifies the P/R reputation you already have.

As an example, if you have 3 paragon and 2 renegade, and you perform a neutral action worth 5 points, you'd end up with 6 Paragon and 4 Renegade.