# What's required to pass the absolute last Charm/Intimidate check?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the last paragon/renegade dialogue option towards the end of the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55186/how-do-you-get-the-last-paragon-renegade-dialogue-option-towards-the-end-of-the)

You know, the third one when talking to

> The Illusive Man

at the end of the game.  My reputation meter looks to be maxed out, or at least fairly close.  Is there anything beyond just rep that influences that check?  The wiki article on the mission seems to indicate that there is more than just rep, but doesn't elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the last Charm/Intimidate you must have attempted to influence TIM in each of the 6 previous conversations with him: once each on Mars, Thessia, and Chronos Station, and 3 times in the final confrontation. Whether the choices were Paragon or Renegade doesn't matter, as long as they weren't neutral. All of those dialogue choices are hidden behind a left-side "investigate" choice, so it's possible that you missed one of them. [Source for what it's worth.](http://redd.it/qmgvc)

Answer (score 2):

To be able to select either of these options, you must have gone full on of either Paragon or Renegade when talking with said character. When interacting with them at all times, you must always go Renegade, or always Paragon to be able to pass the last check.

Comment: So if I used just one neutral dialog option, I'm screwed?  One conversation nearly two games earlier?

Comment: No, I believe this only applies to the ME3 conversations, but I cannot confirm this. Note that there are some "hidden" options on Mars, unlocked by choosing left side conversation options, opening more Renegade/Paragon options on the right side. You will need these also.