# The Paragon/Renegade option towards the end of Mass Effect 3 aren't opening up

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the last paragon/renegade dialogue option towards the end of the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55186/how-do-you-get-the-last-paragon-renegade-dialogue-option-towards-the-end-of-the)

I did every side mission, every option I've ever chosen in the game was paragon, as was the Illusive man options. What gives?