# What happens if I'm able to choose the third paragon dialog option with the illusive man?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the last paragon/renegade dialogue option towards the end of the game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55186/how-do-you-get-the-last-paragon-renegade-dialogue-option-towards-the-end-of-the)

This question will be filled with spoilers.

Despite having played a perfect paragon playthrough, I was unable to select the third paragon dialog choice in the final confrontation with the illusive man. It said something like "but you already have".

I had to choose a normal option, which led to a renegade interrupt that I took, shooting and killing him, but saving Anderson (for a little while at least)

What would've happened if I chose it? Would I have convinced him?

Comment: [Specifically](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55186/how-do-you-get-the-last-paragon-renegade-dialogue-option-towards-the-end-of-the#comment81698_56713)

Comment: hmm... *how* and *what* are different things, but I found the answer in the comments (I hadn't seen it though, it's not an intentional dupe :) )

Comment: Ayup. s'why I linked to the comments. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed this conversation option as well, so I had to look this one up after I completed the game.

If you manage to get the final paragon option, you won't need to take the Renegade option to save Anderson.  Instead, the Illusive Man will realize he is wrong and has been indoctrinated, and he will shoot himself in the head.