# Do renegade points outweigh war assets if I let Samara die?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I soon have to make a decision to let Samara kill herself or not. I am trying to get the highest renegade score possible, but also trying to get as many war-assets to get the best of all the bad endings.

Are the renegade points gained by letting samara kill herself (and kill her daughter) "more" than what I would gain as having Samara as a war asset, as much as they can be compared?

Comment: How do you expect us to compare Renegade reputation points versus War Assets? That's comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: @Mufasa for the purposes of achieving the ending I want, one choice is probably better than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe letting her die will reward you more; However this is purley from memory and may not be entirely accurate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit from having Renegade points - as long as your reputation bar is full, you can handle any charm / intimidate situation as you see fit.

Alternatively, if you happen to like the Mass Effect 3 multiplayer, you can slowly farm that for as many war assets as you need (75 each time you promote), which makes the choice of war assets ultimately irrelevant also.

Comment: So it isn't like in the previous game where you had to make renegade decisions to get renegade dialogue choices?

Comment: @What'supDoc Correct. See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/53166/336) for more info.