# Should I reprogram the Geth Heretics?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2

In Mass Effect 2, Legion says I either reprogram the Geth Heretics or destroy them?

How does this affect Mass Effect 3?

Comment: Related, perhaps: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59270/brokering-peace-between-quarian-and-geth-options-dont-appear

Comment: *shrug*  I just searched the mass effect 3 tag with Heretics, and there it was, in the search results.  I'm certainly no expert on the search options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Destroying the Heretics gives a bonus to settling the

> Quarian/Geth conflict.

If you don't broker peace, either choice yields War Asset bonuses if you remain consistent in your Geth stance, or penalties if you flip-flop.

If you do broker peace, you get a +150 modifier with one faction and -150 modifier with the other faction, depending on your choice with the heretics (either way adds up to 0 net asset modifier - note, you still get a good chunk of assets for brokering peace separate from this modifier (+300) ). Destroying the heretics improves your chance to broker peace.

---

My original concern with reprogramming the heretics is that it would be easy

> for the reapers to reclaim them.

But the choice doesn't influence that.

Comment: @desaivv No, it should not matter if you take one renegade choice.

Comment: What impact do these choices have if you broker peace between them?

Comment: If you broker peace and reprogram the heretics, you get +150 geth assets and -150 quarian assets (modifiers, net to zero).  If you broker peace and destroy the heretics, you get +150 quarian assets and -150 geth assets (modifiers, net to zero).  Destroying the heretics improves your chance to broker peace.