# Am I still able to stop the Quarian from going to war in ME3?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I establish peace between the Geth and the Quarians?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55146/how-do-i-establish-peace-between-the-geth-and-the-quarians)

Although its technically spoiling the game I really want to stop the Geth/Quarian war. I've read up on several questions posted here already which have listed many things you do but none of them have said wether you can still attain peace if you have missed one or two things.

From what I've read, to get the peace options you need to have made the following choices during Mass Effect 2:

1. Stop Tali from being exiled
2. Destroy the heretics in Legions loyalty mission
3. Resolve the Legion/Tali standoff using Renagade/Paragon choice

In addition, I need to make the following choices in Mass Effect 3:

1. Destroy the Geth Squadron on Rannoch (aka fighter base)
2. Save the Admiral Zal on Rannoch (not his men, the admiral)
3. Complete the Legion mission (to make the peace option available)
4. Side with Admiral Han Gerrel not Admiral Ran when they argue over the Radio
5. Side with Tali not Admiral Zen when argueing about retrieving pods or looking for tech

That's a tall order to get perfectly right on a single playthrough, so was wondering if ALL had to be done in order to get the peace option or if some can be missed?

I've only just started out on ME3 so haven't quite got to this point in the game so wanted to know before I got in too deep if I needed to replay ME2 to redo my choices as this is the only part of the game where I want to actually force the outcome, the rest I don't mind about.

From the three options in ME2 I only missed one, choosing to rewrite the Heretics rather than destroy them believing at the time that a good act like this would help make the Geth more open to peace

So basically, is peace still an option?

Comment: Related: [Brokering peace between quarian and geth options don't appear](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59270/brokering-peace-between-quarian-and-geth-options-dont-appear)

Comment: You claim to have read the other questions on the subject, but they *clearly* answer your inquiry; it's a point system and you need to clear a threshold. This question is an exact duplicate.

Comment: Have just been reading the links provided above and they do indeed answer my question now. Thank you all very much for helping