# What is "Legion's Mission in Mass Effect 3?"

Tags: mass-effect-3

Everywhere I look for help in uniting the Geth and the Quarians, I only see Legion's Mission in Mass Effect 3 only referred to as just that: Legion's Mission in Mass Effect 3.

Even here: [How do I establish peace between the Geth and the Quarians?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55146/how-do-i-establish-peace-between-the-geth-and-the-quarians)

And here: [Brokering peace between quarian and geth options don't appear](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59270/brokering-peace-between-quarian-and-geth-options-dont-appear)

...it is only cryptically referred to as "Legion's Mission in Mass Effect 3." There is no indication as to the actual name of the quest, when I receive it, and what prequisites there are, if any.

Answer (score 5):

Primarily, this refers to [Priority: Rannoch](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Priority:_Rannoch), where the major decision point is between Tali and Legion, and the Geth and the quarians.  In addition, Legion's mission also encompasses [Priority: Geth Dreadnought](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Priority:_Geth_Dreadnought), where you first encounter Legion in ME3, as well as [Rannoch: Geth Fighter Squadrons](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Rannoch:_Geth_Fighter_Squadrons) and [Rannoch: Admiral Koris](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Rannoch:_Admiral_Koris), both of which can modify the outcome of the decision point.  It is for this reason that Rannoch: Admiral Koris is included here, despite the fact that Legion isn't involved in the mission.

Answer (score 0):

The mission is actually called "Rannoch: Geth Fighter Squadron" this is the mission where you go into a server in the Geth consensus and work with legion to destroy the server.