# Does morality have any effect?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Reputation work in Mass Effect 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53166/how-does-reputation-work-in-mass-effect-3)

So I've been working towards paragon at every turn and I don't want to have to play through 1,2 and 3 to find out. Does morality (paragon/renegade) change anything other than conversation choices?

Does the story change?
Are there new missions available?
Can I unlock different team members?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it significantly changes the story and how it plays out. The endings in ME1 and 2 were changed significantly due to the choices you made, and what path you went down. ME3 has alternate endings as well, although it seems like your choices don't have near the effect that they did in the earlier games.